# What are the hook parameters passed to external hook program/script?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

The title says it: I am looking for the variable names (HG_*) so I can make use of them in my hook script..

Answer (score 9):

Oben has your best answer, but for specific cases or poorly documented options you can easily test specific hooks using a hook that just prints variables:

```
hg --config hooks.pre-commit="export| grep HG_" commit
```

Where `pre-commit` can be any hook you want to test and `commit` can be any command you want to test.

For example that one showed:

```
export HG_ARGS='commit'
export HG_OPTS='{'"'"'exclude'"'"': [], '"'"'message'"'"': '"''"', '"'"'addremove'"'"': None, '"'"'include'"'"': [], '"'"'close_branch'"'"': None, '"'"'user'"'"': '"''"', '"'"'date'"'"': '"''"', '"'"'logfile'"'"': '"''"', '"'"'mq'"'"': None}'
export HG_PATS='[]'
```

Answer (score 8):

The [hooks section in the hgrc manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) lists all defined hooks, including the environment variables available for each hook.